# iframes within iframes in Google Chrome windows won't open links with target="_blank"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, tabs, window.open

I have a page containing many iframes. These iframes have iframes within them that have links with `target="_blank"`. When I click on them, they do nothing. **How can I get these links to open?**

Comment: I just did a quick test and it works perfectly fine. Links in an iFrame with target="_blank" open in a separate tab window. If the links do absolutely nothing then something must be wrong with the links themselves. At the very least the links should go somewhere. I suggest inspecting the code a bit closer. Something is preventing the links from working.

Comment: I just double-checked the issue. It's actually links in an iframe within an iframe in the opened window. I've updated the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This occurred because I was using the iframe attribute "sandbox" without the correct value.

Comment: What's the correct value?

Answer (score 1):

Use `target="_parent"`.
Also, check different possible values for 'target' attribute here:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp

Answer (score 0):

The [window.top](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_top.asp) property in javascript give you access to the topmost browser window.

The [window.location](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp) property allows you redirect to other pages.

Try redirecting using a combination of top and location:

```
window.top.location.assign("url")
```

Answer (score 0):

**_blank** opens the link in a new tab/window. To reach the most top window, use **target="_top"**.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using JavaScript events instead such as:

```
<a onClick="window.open(...);"></a>
```